# How to insert double tag with select2 tagging

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I would like to show two tags with the same text written in the slect2 search input field. I managed to do that but when the user select one of the two tags then the selection is not shown into the select2 input.

here the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/zgu3y6ro/5/

```
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    
    <div>
      <select id="test" class="form-control" multiple="multiple"></select>
    </div>
    
    $("#test").select2({
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
        createTag: function (params) {
          var term = $.trim(params.term);
    
          if (term === '') {
            return null;
          }
    
          return [
            {
              id: "test1_"+term,
              text: "test1_"+term,
              newTag: "R"
            },
            {
              id: "test2_"+term,
              text: "test2_"+term,
              newTag: "W"
            },
          ]
          
        },
      insertTag: function (data, tag) {
    data.push(tag[0]);
    data.push(tag[1]);
  }
});
```

Anyone can help me? Thank you.